# Python ,aiogram. Отправка стикеров

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Подскажите как в aiogram отправить стикер по его айди.(не айди файла) и можно ли ? 
Если да ,то можно пример. 
Вот айди стикера для примера CAACAgUAAxkBAAIpKV5NII6eNePcBizHxTvVhBvMIgQqAAKgAAPsmmlWQ7EFAgvqUiEYBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё довольно просто.

```
    await message.answer_sticker(r'CAACAgUAAxkBAAIpKV5NII6eNePcBizHxTvVhBvMIgQqAAKgAAPsmmlWQ7EFAgvqUiEYBA')
```

Answer (score 0):

Или так

```
await bot.send_sticker(id получателя,sticker="CAACAgUAAxkBAAIpKV5NII6eNePcBizHxTvVhBvMIgQqAAKgAAPsmmlWQ7EFAgvqUiEYBA" )
```